# error404 accessing Restful web service using jersey framework and tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey, tomcat7

Am facing a problem accessing a Restful web service via this url:
`localhost:8080/PrimNumbers/Generator/strategy`

I got this error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /PrimNumbers/Generator/strategy
>
> type Status report
>
> message /PrimNumbers/Generator/strategy
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

Am using tomcat7.0.81 server and jersey1.17 framework (i have included the jersey jar file under WEB-INF/lib in my project).
here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
version="3.0">
  <display-name>PrimNumbers</display-name>
   <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
      <init-param> 
         <param-name> jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
         <param-value>PrimeNbs</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
   </servlet> 
   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>   
</web-app>
</element
```

>

and this is my service.java(am just testing the service):

```
package PrimeNbs;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


//annotations
@Path("/Generator")

public class PrimeNbsGeneratorService {

    @GET
    @Path("/strategy")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)  
    public String Strategy1(){
        boolean prime=true;
        String rslt="<HTML><h1> Prime numbers: ";
        return(rslt+" test...</h1></HTML>");
    }
}
```

while running my server I got these log msgs:

```
> ug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:PrimNumbers' did not find a matching property.
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.81
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Aug 11 2017 10:21:27 UTC
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.81.0
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            4.4.0-21-generic
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /home/elhem/java/jre1.8.0_121
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/elhem/workspace/tomcat
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/elhem/workspace/tomcat
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/wtpwebapps
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/endorsed
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 865 ms
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.81
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 74 ms
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/webapps/manager
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 67 ms
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 61 ms
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/webapps/docs
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 60 ms
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/webapps/examples
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@51542878')
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/elhem/workspace/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 231 ms
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 22, 2017 11:22:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1397 ms
```

Can anyone help! I will be so appreciating.

Comment: You're using the wrong init-param. The one you are using is for Jersey 2.x. You are using 1.x. Look for a 1.x example. The init-param name for the package scanning should start with `com.sun.jersey`

Comment: thanks peeskillet, but I have tried with : com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages   but am still having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your web.xml.

You now create a servlet with the name `Jersey RESTful Application` and a mapping for a servlet with the name `PrimNumbers`. But the servler `PrimNumbers` does not exists.

So what you need to do is make the servletand servlet-mapping use the same name.

Like this:

```
  <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
      <init-param> 
         <param-name> jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
         <param-value>PrimeNbs</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
  </servlet> 
  <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: thank you Chris for the answer, I have change it but am still facing the same problem!